# Iterating (yield) over a list

Tags: python, list, iteration, yield

I'm trying to make a method that iterates over a list and returns the next element.

That's my list:

> [2, 5, 7, 10, 25, 30, 50, 70]

That's the method I'm working on:

```
    def iterDenominations(self):
        it = iter(self.listDenominations)
        yield it.__next__()
```

When I call the method and print the result

```
firstCall = C.iterDenominations()
print(firstCall)
secondCall = C.iterDenominations()
print(secondCall)
```

, the first two prints are:

> <generator object Currency.iterDenominations at 0x000001D413F6DC10>

> <generator object Currency.iterDenominations at 0x000001D4140E2EB0>

What should I do to print '2', '5', '7', ...?
Thanks you

Comment: do not use the dunder methods `__xxxxx__(...)`. why not `yield from self.listDenominations` ?

Comment: Please update the question with the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` always creates a new generator. `iterDenominations` doesn't return the next/first element of `self.listDenominations`; it returns a generator that will yield that single element.

If you want to create your own iterator, you can do it the long with with

```
def iterDenominations(self):
    it = iter(self.listDenominations)
    for x in it:
        yield x
```

the shorter way

```
def iterDenominations(self):
    for x in self.listDenominations:
        yield x
```

or an even shorter way:

```
def iterDenominations(self):
    yield from self.listDenominations
```

or the shortest way

```
def iterDenominations(self):
    return iter(self.listDenominations)
```

(OK, that's actually two characters longer. But it might look more familiar.)

Comment: Thanks you. I would like to save the single next element by using an iterator. I don't know if that's the correct definition, sorry, I'm new to python

Comment: @goalpang Do you mean you want to both store the yielded element in a variable and yield it?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I think so. I would like to have 2 in firstCall variable, 5 in secondCall variable and so on

Answer (score 0):

For that to work, you need to store the state somewhere and then a custom function is a difficult start. I believe you want to use the iterator as it is:

```py
it = iter(my_list)
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
```